# How to sort a set of XML results based on bid value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I'm probably missing missing something real simple here.

I've an XML feed. I know how to parse the XML itself, but how do I turn, say, an array of objects like:

`[
 {bid:"0.001", title:'test title', description:'test description'}, 
 {bid:"0.025", title:'why are you', description:'still reading'}
]`

..into an array where I know that array[0] will fetch me the XML result object with the highest bid - meaning, I need to scan through the objects inside and sort them by highest bid.

I've messed around with jquery's filter but I can't get it to work.

Comment: it is not xml, it is json

Comment: It certainly comes in as XML. I figured adding the relevant listings to an array of objects is not a bad start to sorting them is all. Whether I get XML or json as input is kind of irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort an array using custom sorting function:

```
your_array.sort(sortByBid);


sortByBid = function(a, b) {
    var a_bid = parseFloat(a.bid);        
    var b_bid = parseFloat(b.bid);
    if (a_bid === b_bid) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (a_bid > b_bid ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code then. Above snippet will result in "your_array" being sorted by bid.

Comment: It's far too long. I'll explore your tidbit of code instead. Will this work on more than 2 array members?

Comment: Your array could be of any size with any hash-like objects as long as they have "bid" field.

Comment: Ok what's weird is that if I don't do array = array.sort(); it works fine. As if it's a .sort! if you know what I mean.

Comment: To clarify, I simply left out the assignment part and it got sorted properly. Comment our your code and the lowest number is at the beginning again. But if the assignment is there, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Likely a typo the first time around

Comment: Of course... sort() is "in place" method. I've updated the answer.